# Is it possible for a background app to always have access to camera?

Tags: android

I am trying to make a app that will run in the background while the user uses his/her phone. I would not like to reveal the functions of the app but I can guarantee you that I will not use this app for spying purposes.

So my main question is that if I manage to develop the app, can my app always access the camera of the phone? Is this possible?

Comment: I think foreground Service can do this for you.

Comment: I don't think Google would believe **I can guarantee you that I will not use this app for spying purposes.**

Comment: Not possible. Here is documentations -> https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera#considerations

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I will go try it out. @NoumanCh

Comment: Only if you build your own ROM

Answer (score 1):

"On Android 9 (API level 28) and later, apps running in the background cannot access the camera. Therefore, you should use the camera either when your app is in the foreground or as part of a foreground service." 
from docs - https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera